# Handle 'match-parent' images

Tags: android, layout, imageview

Let's say I have an ImageView like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:src="@drawable/pic.png" />
```

I will have different sizes for **pic.png** in many folders:

- drawable-mdpi: 100*100px
- drawable-hdpi: 150*150px
- drawable-xhdpi: 200*200px
- drawable-xxhdpi: 300*300px

Now, if I have this ImageView

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"
  android:src="@drawable/pic.png" />
```

**What sizes should my images in `drawable-*` be?** My ImageView will obviously be matching the screen bounds.
Thanks

Comment: What sizes shoud you use where? You already told you want match_parent

Comment: You’ll have to be clearer on what you’re trying to achieve. What exactly do you mean by _What sizes should I use_?

Answer (score 0):

You should create images of differents sizes and put them in its corresponding folders, `drawable-mdpi`,  `drawable-hdpi` etc. Check the article of [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html). You need to start at a scale, for example `xxxhdpi`, and from there scale down your images for densities mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. Based on the docs, you should follow this:

> *“So where do you begin when designing for multiple screens? One approach is to work in the base standard (normal size and MDPI) and scale it up or down for the other buckets. Another approach is to start with the device with the largest screen size, and then scale down and figure out the UI compromises you'll need to make on smaller screens.”*

[image: Densities]

Comment: Yes I know this. I updated my question. I want to know what size (in pixels) my real files in drawable-* should be ?

Comment: Ok. I think I'm not clear. For a 100dp imageview, I would have a 100*100 px image in drawable-mdpi. But for a 'match_parent' imageview, what size should my picture be, in drawable-mdpi?

Comment: @RomainPellerin dp and px are two different things. Here you need to focus on px. If you start with a 50x50px image size for mdpi, HDPI should be 75x75 px, XHDPI 100x100px and so on. Then in your xml you can specify the with and heigh in terms of dpi (for density).